# CXF web service under JBoss6 deployment error

Tags: jakarta-ee, cxf, jboss6.x

I am writing a web service using CXF and running under JBoss 6.0.0.Final. Right now, I have a simple web service class with one method, just for testing. My war is not getting deployed. I am getting the following exception when my war is being deployed.

```
13:55:27,354 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/cxfws]] **Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/AbstractFileResolvingResource**
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.7.0]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:260) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.getResourceByPath(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:153) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader.getResource(DefaultResourceLoader.java:102) [:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:280) [:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1227) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:177) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
.....
```

The project is a maven project and I have spring jar dependencies since I will be writing bean classes later.

Your help appreciated.

Comment: That log suggests it's finding version 2.5.5 of "org.springframework.core.io" but version 3.0.5.RELEASE of the other spring classes.

Comment: I changed the maven dependency to cxf-bundle-jaxrs as specified in the apache cxf web site, and I am getting a different error: 

  Deployment "vfs:///D:/JBoss6/server/default/deploy/cxfws.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatc
hException: Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm org.jboss.xb.annotations.JBossXmlS
chema.elementFormDefault() (Found data of type Ljavax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlNsForm;.QUALIFIED)

Comment: You'd better update your post and add a new stack trace. Keep also in mind that JBoss VFS is supported by Spring from 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is funny but I made some exclusions (jaxb-api, jaxb-impl, jetty, geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec, stax-api) in the pom.xml and it worked. Some of the exclusions (geronimo, jetty) were suggested by my colleague. But I have no idea how this is related to the error. Anybody?